# How to make particles of an object that is made of several arrayed objects?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I made a lupine with an array of leaves and 3 different arrays of flowers(for different sizes of the buds). Now I want to make a particle system of this whole lupine. Is there any workaround to do it without connecting all those meshes as I really want to keep it procedural?

[image]

----edit----

So sorry I don't know why I typed array instead of particle, I mean I want to use the whole lupine in a PARTICLE system to make a bunch of them. I tried to make an instance of the collection, then put it in a collection then choose it in the particle system, but nothing comes out.

Comment: Put it in a collection and instance the collection.

Comment: Make sure the object you are instantiated from (your environment mesh for instance) is not in the same collection as you flower meshes. You don't need to create a "Collection Instance", there is an option in the particle settings where you choose what to render for the particles, you can then use a drop down menu to choose "Collection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had a quick player around with a scene I just made.

1. You have to make sure that the object (in my case plane) is in a sperate collection to the the lupin objects.
2. In the "Particle Properties" tab in the outliner toggle "Advanced" in Hair to get the some more options you might need.
3. Under the "Render" tab, switch "Render As" to Collection (which I believe you did). In the same options toggle "Whole Collection" in order for it to emit the whole lupin/object as one and not random segments.
4. In my case (you may not have to) Under the "Rotation" settings I had to change the "Orientation Axis" to Global Y, but have a play around with it, it may be different in your case.

**Note** You should play around with the "Hair Length" under emission tab in conjuncture with the "Scale" under the "Render" tab in particle properties to get the size you want.

[image: Same Collection]

[image: Separate collection]

[image: Outliner Settings]

Comment: Thank you a bunch mate!! I didn't know the "Whole Collection" is for this purpose!

Comment: No worries mate glad I could help, all the best with your work! If you could mark the answer as answered with the tick that would greatly help me as well :)